# Running A MySQL-Based DNS Server, Which Technology I should chose in 2019?

Tags: mysql, dns, reverse-dns

Hello StackOverflow citizens!

Please tell me the up to date method to store DNS data on MySQL Server.

ps: I have set up the BIND9 on 2 servers and its running good, I can set up any domain on my own domain-dns, but also I need to store the bid9 data(or any other) in SQL base and I found it difficult to do with the BIND9. 
Maybe OpenDNS?

I'm a total newbie and I do not know is there any working solution to this: DNS+SQL??

I have found manual from 2006 year, but it's 2019 already and I guess there should be some stacks of "frameworks" or technologies to do it.

Comment: PowerDNS has a mysql-backend (amongst many others), works quite good, although it is not really a high-performance solution

Comment: Hey @Ctx thanks for the answer, please can you tell which solution is better or which solution will be high-performance?

Comment: I am not aware of a high-performance solution with a database backend, since the database queries always have an adverse impact. Yes, you can cache the requests, but you still have to ask the database for i.e. unknown names or to refresh the data. You could build a hybrid solution with bind 9; hourly generate bind zonefiles from the database and reload the nameserver.